# How can I make my ui-router application default to a state?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Sorry if my question title is not very clear here's more details. My application config has these states:

```
    var home = {
        name: 'home',
        template: '<div data-ui-view></div>',
        url: '/'
    };

    var homeAccess = {
        name: 'home.access',
        url: 'access',
        templateUrl: 'app/access/partials/webapi.html'
    };
```

How can I make it so that when a user enters the URL for my application as:

- www.url.com
- www.url.com/index.html
- www.url.com/access

that it goes to the homeAccess state?

Note that I am using a web.config for my application in Visual Studio:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I'm also using Amazon Cloudfront to serve the production version of the application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inject $urlRouterProvider into your route config file and add the following code there:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise( function($injector) {
    var $state = $injector.get("$state");
    $state.go('home');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick advice. I will check this out and mark as answered if it works for me.  It will take me a little bit of time to check out as I have some other things not working that are not related to this :-(

Comment: Take your time, also if you can post the full code of your route file that would be better for us to help you.

Comment: If I have as my URL www.abc.com/home/access, rather than have it go just to home is it possible to make it download the application index.html and then go to /home/access ?

Comment: As I know that is how it works by default, it loads /home route and then /home/access, so both views are loaded, anyway you can see examples in the official website: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state